ADC ADS1263 maximum sampling
I'm using the library in python: Python ADS1263.
The code which currently works for me looks like this:
def adcMonitor(conn):
    ADC = ADS1263.ADS1263()
    ADC.ADS1263_SetMode(1)
    ADC.ADS1263_init_ADC1('ADS1263_14400SPS')

    while True:
        if (conn.recv() == "start"):
            running = True
            buffer = []
            lastValue = 0
            while (running == True):

                # Should we stop?
                if (conn.poll()):
                    if (conn.recv() == "stop"):
                        running = False

                # Get value and make sure it's unique
                nextValue = ADC.ADS1263_GetChannalValue(0)
                if (nextValue != lastValue):
                    buffer.append(ADC.ADS1263_GetChannalValue(0))

            # Send back the ADC readings
            conn.send(buffer)


parent_conn, child_conn = Pipe()
p = Process(target=adcMonitor, args=(child_conn,))
p.start()

But when I set sampling higher than 14400SPS, i. e. 19200SPS or maximum 38400SPS after some time the function writes noise instead of signal to buffer. After changing back to 14400SPS, I have to restart Raspberry Pi to make the ADS1263 work correctly again.
What is the reason of this noise (when the ADS1263 stuck) and what should I do to let me register signal with higher sampling?
